# Error on HQL query with parameter

Tags: parameters, hql

I have the following classes defining a ManyToMany relation between *Students* and *Courses*.

Courses class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String title;
private String sched;
private int    units;

// The students enrolled in this class
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

public Course() {
    // empty const required by java bean
}

public Course(String course_id, String title, String sched, int units) {
    this.id = course_id;
    this.title = title;
    this.sched = sched;
    this.units = units;
}


@Id
@Column(name = "COURSE_ID")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    // Other setters/getters with mapping...

@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course_join",
         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID"),
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID"))
public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return this.students;
   }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
   }


   public String toString() {
    return "Course - Id: " + id + " Title: " + title + " Sched: " + 
            sched + "Units: " + units;
   }
}
```

Students class:

```
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

public Student() {
    // empty constructor
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Set<Course> course) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.courses = courses;
}

// Setters and getters with Hibernate annotations

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    // Other setters/getters....

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "student_course_join",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID"))
public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

public void addCourse(Course course) {  

    // get course list and add the course to it
    getCourses().add(course);
    course.addStudent(this);   

}

public void dropCourse(Course course) {

    // Remove the course from the course list
    getCourses().remove(course);
    course.dropStudent(this);   

}

} // Class
```

The following HQL query works fine:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct c from Course c left join fetch 
                                                         c.students where c.id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", id);

Course course = (Course)query.uniqueResult();
```

The coure object is returned with a valid students list. I'm having trouble querying for just course information. I am using the following query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct c from Course c where c.id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", id);
course = (Course)query.uniqueResult();
```

I get the following HQL exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   edu.univ.mht.domain.Course.students, no session or session was closed
>       .....

In this case I am not interested in retrieving a student list, but Hibernate seems to be complaining about something related to the student list. The course I am searching on has a valid student list. I get this exception even if I search on a course in the db which has no student list.

Here is the HQL generated for the query:

```
Hibernate: select course0_.COURSE_ID as COURSE1_0_, course0_.SCHED as SCHED0_, course0_.TITLE as TITLE0_, course0_.UNITS as UNITS0_ from course course0_ where course0_.COURSE_ID=?
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: edu.univ.mht.domain.Course.students, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstAnd.getValue(AstAnd.java:43)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:986)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.course_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(course_jsp.java:167)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.course_jsp._jspService(course_jsp.java:93)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
May 8, 2013 7:28:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/mht] threw 
exception [javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'empty' on type   
org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of 
role: edu.univ.mht.domain.Course.students, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstAnd.getValue(AstAnd.java:43)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:986)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.course_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(course_jsp.java:167)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.course_jsp._jspService(course_jsp.java:93)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: First, your mapping is wrong. One of the sides has to be the inverse side, using the meppedBy attribute, and must not define the join table used, since it's already defined at the other side. Second: why use a HQL query to do what Session.get() does, in a better way? Third, post the stack trace of the exception. I bet that the exception is not caused by the query, but by some code using the course later and accessing its students list, that has not been loaded.

Comment: I did try the mapping you suggest, in the Course class instead of the current mapping I tried both                   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: I also tried @ManyToMany(mappedBy="coures", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) in the Course class and had trouble saving and deleting students with both.

Comment: JB - I just went back and changed the mapping in the Course class and changed the mapping to @ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses") and got the same error. I tried to add in fetch=FetchType.LAZY and it had no effect. I also tried using session.get(Course.class, id) and got the same results. I'm kind of out of ideas. - Thanks much Mike

Comment: Look at the stack trace. The exception doesn't happen when the query is executed. It happens in the JSP, when you try to display the students of the course. You loaded the course without initializing its students, so obviously, you get this exception. Make sure to initailize the students (by calling `course.getStudents().size()`, for example), while the session is still open (in your service or DAO).

Comment: Thanks very much for your patients and help JB. I changed the mapping back to what it should be and things seem to work now. I fixed the check in my jsp for a null or empty list. I guess the list was always present. If I query for the course without student details I use session.get(Course.class, id) and it returns the class but with a list of students. Not sure if get() should do this. If I select to specifically query course with a list of students I use the query "select distinct c from Course c left join fetch c.students where c.id = :id". Either way I get a student list? Thanks again.

Comment: If a student has courses, whatever the way you get the student from the database, Hibernate will always return its list of courses. In the first case, the list will be lazy-loaded, whereas in the second case, it will be eagerly loaded. Lazy-loaded means: as soon as you call a method of the student list, Hibernate executes a query to populate this list, and then executes the method. Of course, this can only work if the session is still open. If not, you get a LazyInitializationException.

Comment: Thanks again JB, appreciate it.